# Facebook Graph API - Ordering Items

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working with the graph API at the moment and I am trying to order posts by the number of comments on it.

While it seems like it should be pretty straight forward, I can't seem to get it to work. They have a parameter for "limit" and "offset", but nothing for orderby (in their documentation anyway).

https://graph.facebook.com/platform/posts

Basically I want to order something like this by number of comments. But yea, totally lost... If anyone can help me, it would be much appreciated!

(I've seen some FQL examples, but I am not sure how I can grab posts via FQL or even how I can execute FQL by simply using CURL)

Thanks,

--d

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use a sorting library yourself. I used this in my program as well, with the JSON output it shouldn't be too hard to sort them.